# How to convert a correctly formatted Javascript object (in string format) to an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains all the characters for a javascript object:

```
string_object = "{question_text: 'q 1', ans_1: 'yes', ans_2: 'no'},
{question_text: 'q 2', ans_1: 'United', ans_2: 'City'},
{question_text: 'q 3', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},
{question_text: 'q 4', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},
{question_text: 'q 5', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},
{question_text: 'q 6', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},"
```

I want to convert this to a javascript object, so I can do all sorts of useful things with it like object[0].question_text.

Is there a way of converting this directly to an object? The answers I've seen involve basically regex'ing the string to change it to perfect JSON, and then JSON.parse() it.

Comment: it's not a [JSON](http://json.org) compliant string, but with `eval`, ...

Comment: Fix whatever's serving you that string so it serves you proper JSON instead, then, yes, `JSON.parse`. Don't try to turn it to JSON on the Javascript side here IMO (even though you could), that's an X solution to an X/Y problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this out

```js
var string_object = "{question_text: 'q 1', ans_1: 'yes', ans_2: 'no'},{question_text: 'q 2', ans_1: 'United', ans_2: 'City'},{question_text: 'q 3', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},{question_text: 'q 4', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},{question_text: 'q 5', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},{question_text: 'q 6', ans_1: 'over', ans_2: 'under'},"

var obj = eval('(['+string_object+'])')

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: with JSON.parse there should be only double quotes in both values and keys